# Solve the following initial value problem: $2y''+y'-y=e^{3t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$
2y''+y'-y=e^{3t}; \text{ with } y(0)=2,\ y'(0)=0
$$

I got to this point:

$$
L(y)=\frac{1}{(s-3)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{(2s-1)(s+1)}
$$

but now I'm not sure what to do with these polynomials. I know that the inverse Laplace of $\dfrac{1}{(s-3)^2}$ would be $\dfrac{te^{3t}}{1!}$, but because it is being multiplied by another polynomial I don't think it can be separated. Could someone guide me on the right track here?

Comment: I think you should decompose that fraction first and then use a table.

Answer (score 3):

In general, when you do Laplace transforms, you need to do partial fraction decomposition to separate all the terms:
$$L(y)=\frac{1}{(s-3)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{2s-1}\cdot\frac{1}{s+1}$$
$$\frac{1}{(s-3)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{2s-1}\cdot\frac{1}{s+1}=\frac{A}{s-3}+\frac{B}{(s-3)^2}+\frac{C}{2s-1}+\frac{D}{s+1}$$
Clear the denominator:
$$1=(s-3)(2s-1)(s+1)A+(2s-1)(s+1)B+(s-3)^2(s+1)C+(s-3)^2(2s-1)D$$
Solve for the coefficients by selecting values of $s$:
$$s=3: ~ 1=0A+20B+0C+0D \rightarrow B=\frac{1}{20}$$
$$s=\frac{1}{2}: ~ 1=0A+0B+\frac{25}{4}\frac{3}{2}C+0D \rightarrow C=\frac{8}{75}$$
$$s=-1: ~ 1=0A+0B+0C-48D \rightarrow D=\frac{-1}{48}$$
Since we have a repeated root, pick a different value of $s$:
$$s=0: ~ 1=3A-B+9C-9D \rightarrow A=\frac{-13}{400}$$
So your problem is now:
$$L(y)=\frac{-13}{400}\frac{1}{s-3}+\frac{1}{20}\frac{1}{(s-3)^2}+\frac{8}{75}\frac{1}{2s-1}+\frac{-1}{48}\frac{1}{s+1}$$
This can be easily inverse transformed, thus providing your solution!

Comment: Why did you choose $B$ to put over $(s-3)^2$ and not $Bx+C$? The denominator has a degree of 2 when foiled out.

Comment: Good question! It's because this is a repeated root. In that case, you don't have to use the $Bx+C$ form. For general quadratics, you do need to use that form. What you would find in this case is that $B=0$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You also needn't use the Laplace transform here. Your Ansatz could be $Ae^{3x}$ and you would have

$18Ae^{3x}+3Ae^{3x}-Ae^{3x}=e^{3x}$

$18A+3A-A=1$

which gives you the particular solution. The solution to the homogenous equation, as you know, will be a linear combination of $e^{r_1x}$ and $e^{r_2x}$. Then you can plug in the initial values. To me, this seems simpler than the transform.